# Solve $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{1}^{\pi}\frac{\cos(\frac{x}{n})}{1-e^{-xn}}dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

> I have to determine $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{1}^{\pi}f_n(x)\,dx$ with $f_n: [1,\pi]\to \mathbb{R}, f_n(x):=\frac{\cos(\frac{x}{n})}{1-e^{-xn}}$.

How can I determine the limit of this integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's take a look at $\frac{1}{1-e^{-xn}}$. As a function of $x$, $e^{-xn}$ is decreasing; therefore $1-e^{-xn}$ increases with $x$, and $\frac{1}{1-e^{-xn}}$ decreases.

Therefore we know that for all $n$ and for all $x\in[1,\pi]$,
$$
\frac{1}{1-e^{-\pi n}}\leq\frac{1}{1-e^{-xn}}\leq\frac{1}{1-e^{-n}}.
$$
Now, consider the cosine term. The cosine function is decreasing on $[0,\pi]$; so, in particular, for all $n$ and for all $x\in[0,\pi]$, we have
$$
\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)\leq\cos\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)\leq\cos(0)=1.
$$
for $n\geq 2$ (since for $n\geq 2$, $\cos(\frac{x}{n})\geq0$ on $[0,\pi]$).

Combining these two estimates,
$$
\frac{\cos(\frac{\pi}{n})}{1-e^{-\pi n}}\leq\frac{\cos(\frac{x}{n})}{1-e^{-xn}}\leq\frac{1}{1-e^{-n}},
$$
and therefore (by integrating each) we have
$$
\frac{(\pi-1)\cos(\frac{\pi}{n})}{1-e^{-\pi n}}\leq\int_1^{\pi}\frac{\cos(\frac{x}{n})}{1-e^{-xn}}\,dx\leq\frac{\pi-1}{1-e^{-n}}
$$
for all $n$.

But, these left and right limits should be very straight-forward to calculate. Can you see how?

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it is $cos(\frac{x}{n})$ and not $cos(\frac{\pi}{n})$.

Comment: @JimButton edited.